# wordpress embed not working for some youtube videos

Tags: wordpress

I have a video gallery page in wordpress, http://rabindraadhikari.com/category/videos/. I am using the embed shortcode:

```
   <?php 
    $embedurl = wp_filter_nohtml_kses(get_the_content());
    if (!empty($embedurl)) {
           $frame= apply_filters('the_content', "[embed]" . $embedurl . "[/embed]");
        echo $frame;
    }
    ?>
```

But some videos are not embeded(first 3 are not working in this case). I have done everything i can to make it work. But i could not figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: i solved the problem by extracting the video id using a regular expression and manually creating a iframe with the embed src. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD: I suggest using default youtube embed code. So you will have something like

```
<?php 
  $embedurl = wp_filter_nohtml_kses(get_the_content());
  if (!empty($embedurl)) {
         $frame= apply_filters('the_content', '<object width="420" height="315" data="' . strip_tags($embedurl) . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></object>');
      echo $frame;
  }
?>
```

Comment: its not working since the embed url is in form of "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vb2ZyEIsWGM" but src excepts url in form of "https://www.youtube.com/embed/uOhgyRNPms8"

Comment: try this <object width="420" height="315" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"></object>
object tag works with direct youtube urls

Comment: did not work. why the normal embed is not working only for some urls?

Comment: WordPress Media Uploader allows users to upload images, documents, videos and audios creating a return reference link of the selected media files directly on the post. https://www.wpblog.com/embed-wordpress-videos-audios-images/

Answer (score 1):

Some videos may not be embedded because the video's owner on YouTube has disabled embedding. Visit the video's YouTube page and look under "Embed". It may say: "Embedding disabled by request".

Here is an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l6Hfk13LZIQ).